# Create an label by another class

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel

I'm trying to create a label, when I call a function. But I can't do this.. How to do it? I want to create a label through `funcoes.test()` method (below the first code), to show in `JFrame` (first class, named `Interface`)

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:,
    System.out.print("test");
    for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.print("hi");
        this.button = new JButton();
        this.button.setSize(60, 50);
        this.button.setLocation(50+(80*i), 100);
        this.button.setVisible(true);
        this.button.setText("" + i);
        this.button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                int op = Integer.parseInt(ae.getActionCommand());
                funcoes.test(op);

            }  
        });
        this.add(button);
        this.jPanel1.add(button);
        this.revalidate();
        this.repaint();


    }
}
```

Here's my other class:

```
public class funcoes extends Interface {
    public static void test(int x) {
        System.out.print("Hi: " + x);
        JLabel numero = new JLabel();
        JLabel total = new JLabel();
        //Interface.        
}
```

Comment: pls post the whole example

Comment: Please post a compilable and runnable example that makes sense. Please correct the English and the description in your question as it is not easy to understand.

Comment: You need to e able to add your labels to something...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `Interface` class is a subclass of `JFrame` (I think this is what you mean in *to show in JFrame (first class, named Interface)*), just call the add method:

```
JLabel numero = new JLabel();
JLabel total = new JLabel();
add(numero);
add(total);
```

To have a nice layout, you may use one of the [`LayoutManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)s.